# DataGrid generates empty rows

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

I have two threads - let's name them Calc thread and UI thread. Inside the Calc thread I refreshes an ObservableCollection. I also have a handler for the CollectionCHanged event of the ObservableCollection. As I know, the handler executes within the same thread that raises the CollectionChanged event - so that is the same thread that refreshes the ObservableCollection in my case. So, to refresh UI I can't use bindings directly as in single-threaded application - UI must be refreshed manually through Dispatcher. But when I use DataGrid in the UI I get the empty rows instead of any data, and when I use ListBox, for example, the appropriate data is showed:

data grid case to the left, list box case to the right

(list box is just for example that the data binds and shows; I don't want the data to be showed like in this list box, but like in data grid (if it worked as I expect - not as in case on the picture) - table with column titles)

[image]

Well, I prepared the code, which you can copy and paste to reconstruct the problem:

C#

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Integer { get; set; }
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }    

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            MyCollection.CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() 
                        {
                            Integer = i, 
                            Str = "String" + i
                        });
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }));

            t.Start();
        }

        void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(
            object sender, 
            NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(
                () =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                        dataGrid.Items.Add((MyClass)item);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

XAML (just comment/uncomment the list box case and the data grid case):

```xml
<Window
  x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Grid>

    <!--<ListBox Name="dataGrid">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Integer}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Str}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>-->

    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
      <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Integer}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Str}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
    </DataGrid>

  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `DataGrid` is a very complex control. Its `ItemTemplate` does not work normally (we rarely use it). I don't think we can change the designed layout of DataGrid that is like a ***grid*** which should have some columns (at least 1). In this case you have not declared any column for the datagrid, the `AutoGenerateColumns` seem not to work when adding items directly to `Items` property. So all you see are just empty rows. Try adding some explicit `DataGridTextColumn` and set the Binding correctly, you'll see it works. But again I don't see the role of `ItemTemplate` here, it's simply useless here.

Comment: if you want some result rendered like in the ListBox, you can just use 1 `DataGridTemplateColumn` then edit the `CellTemplate` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

C#

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Integer { get; set; }
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                   Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                   {
                    MyCollection.Add(new MyClass()
                    {
                        Integer = i,
                        Str = "String " + i
                    });
                   }));
                }
            }));

            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<Window
  x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Integer}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Str}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.ItemTemplate>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Other method is to use another List:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private List<MyClass> _MyCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection { get; set; }

        private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            _MyCollection = new List<MyClass>();
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500);
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    _MyCollection.Add(new MyClass()
                    {
                        Integer = i,
                        Str = "String " + i
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }));

            t.Start();
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_MyCollection.Count != MyCollection.Count)
            {
                MyCollection.Add(_MyCollection[_MyCollection.Count - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Second edit with you example:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int Integer { get; set; }
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<MyClass> _MyCollection;
        public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            _MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
            _MyCollection.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(_MyCollection_CollectionChanged);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    _MyCollection.Add(new MyClass()
                    {
                        Integer = i,
                        Str = "String " + i
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }));

            t.Start();
        }

        private void _MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(
                () =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                        MyCollection.Add((MyClass)item);
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, something like this. But if the example become more complex and I have many hierarchical functions calls inside thread "t" - have I to send the Dispatcher object through all the function calls?

Comment: I added another method. There are many more methods to handle actualisation in your GUI, but I don't know what you want to do in your extra thread. Is your extra thread "t" a critical thread and it is not allowed to block it?

Edit: Or you make a second ObservableCollection and do it like you do in your example.

Comment: Oh, I see. In the last example I do the work with _MyCollection in the background thread and refresh the MyCollection in the GUI thread through Dispatcher. And - that is important - I bind exactly the MyCollection to the GUI. Am I right?

Comment: Well, I tried that I described before - and it works! Thank you! The last example is more suitable for me.